# Override list.phtml Magento 2.2.2

Tags: theme, magento2.2, theme-overriding

I have a custom `list.phtml` file in

> `app\design\frontend\BSS\ContactUs\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml`

And I want to override it on

> `\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml`

How to make it work?

Comment: just want to clarify if BSS here your package and ContactUs is theme?

Comment: it's company and theme, yes but does it matter?

Comment: Are all the other customization in this theme working?Is your theme being correctly configured to use in frontend?

Comment: yes it's, if i change the theme in vendor it's working, but somehow can't override it in app/design

Comment: Did you applied your theme to be used as a theme from `Content > design configuration` in your Magento from your Magento admin? if yes then try to refresh your cache & then see the changes

Answer (score 4):

For override list.phtml via custom module

Create **view/frontend/layout/catalog_category_view.xml** and put this code.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magetest_Test::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Next create new file **view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml** set your code.

Comment: This is not required when overriding is done through theme, this is useful when you are overriding in the custom module.

Answer (score 1):

Create a below file in mention path with below code.

> app\design\frontend\BSS\ContactUs\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_category_view.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="category.products.list"   >
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Magento_Catalog::product/list.phtml</argument>
            </action>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: i have tried this too but it also not working at all

Comment: Make sure your layout should be 2 column left.

Answer (score 0):

For override list.phtml

```
\vendor\magento\module-catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\list.phtml
```

Copy this file to your theme

```
app\design\frontend\BSS\ContactUs\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\list.phtml
```

And apply custimization as per your requirement

Comment: i did it, after that i flush cache but it still not work

Comment: have you checked using path hint? which while is called now

Comment: Flush cache using ssh

Comment: still not working i have checked the path carefully but it still using the vendor/magento path not my path

Comment: is your theme active perfectly? rest of other file are called form your theme

Comment: i'm just trying to change the add to cart button to contact us via theme override, so what i do i copy the list.phtml in vendor and create a path like above, throw the list in then edit, that's all

Comment: @NavinBhudiya product list block is cachable, try run php bin/magento setup:upgrade & php bin/magento setup:di:compile & php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deploy

Comment: have u tried php bin/magento setup:upgrade & php bin/magento setup:di:compile & php bin/magento -f setup:static-content:deplo?
@user63384

Answer (score 0):

create block file and the file should extend `ListProduct`.

```
<?php
namespace Frontname\Modulename\Block\Crosssell;

class Autocrosssell extends \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct
{
  //your functions
}

?>
```

Create view/frontend/layout/checkout_cart_index.xml and put this code.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="1column" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="Magento_Swatches::css/swatches.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="checkout.cart.items">
            <block class="Frontname\Modulename\Block\Crosssell\Autocrosssell" name="custom.products.list" as="product_list" template="Frontname_Modulename::checkout/cart/list.phtml">
              <!--   <container name="category.product.list.additional" as="additional" /> -->
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\RendererList" name="category.product.type.details.renderers" as="details.renderers">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" as="default"/>
                </block>
                <referenceBlock name="category.product.type.details.renderers">
                           <block class="Magento\Swatches\Block\Product\Renderer\Listing\Configurable" as="configurable" template="Magento_Swatches::product/listing/renderer.phtml" />
                </referenceBlock>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Try this